# use a separate webpage to refresh an excel htm file

Tags: html, excel

I tried doing a search to find my answer, but wasn't coming up with much.

I took an excel spreadsheet that's used as a schedule, and published a copy as an .htm file with the attributes that it would auto-republish anytime the excel file was updated and saved.

This htm file is saved on a local server, and everyone can type in the web address and view the schedule.

Obviously I can't go in and add something like  in the htm file because I'm guessing it would get overwritten and erased every time the excel file is updated.

I'm not a web programmer, just a network admin. Is there a way to use another html page to bring up the original htm file, but also have an auto-refresh function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could add some VBA to your Excel to export as html on save event.

Comment: This is just a thought, what if you added the current date / time to the file name when exporting it to an htm file. That way you wouldn't need to use file io processes to determine the last modified date / time. Just parse the file name string for that info.

Comment: My previous thought might not work because of the always changing file name.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use another html page to bring up the original htm file, but also have an auto-refresh function?

Yes, you could create another HTML file. In this file you create an iframe Element and target it to the Excel created HTML-File. With some JavaScript you can refresh the iframe after a few seconds.

A possible solution would be look like this:

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('FrameID').contentWindow.location.reload(true);    
}, 3000);
</script>
<iframe id="FrameID" src="youExcelFile.htm" width="95%" height="100">
  <p>Browser dont support Iframes</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks.

I researched iframe and came up with the following:

<iframe src="http://schedule.htm"  width="20000" height="1200">

which works fine I think. Now I want to see about displaying the time and date the web page was last modified.

I first tried using

<script language="Javascript">
document.write("This page was last modified on: " + document.lastModified +"");
</SCRIPT>

but it seemed to update whenever my webpage auto updated, so it wasn't a true representation of when the web page file was last updated.